# Roscosmos: Government agency, state-owned corporation, or something else?

Tags: russia, law, roscosmos

Exactly what kind of organization is [Roscosmos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roscosmos)?

- An agency of the government, like NASA?  We seem to treat it as such in this site.
- A state-owned corporation, like the old Soviet design bureaus?  The first sentence of the Wikipedia article suggests as such, but the rest of that article leaves me confused if this is currently the case.
- A privately-owned corporation, like SpaceX?
- Something else?

Please support your answer with a non-Wikipedia source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It's currently a state-owned corporation

---

According to [this news article](https://tass.com/science/847295) (which is linked as source in the German Wikipedia) Roscosmos was a Goverment agency until Jan 1st 2016 when a decree to abolish the Federal Space Agency and turn it into a state-run space corporation came into force that president Putin signed in July 2015.

The [Roscosmos homepage](http://en.roscosmos.ru/119/) matches this:

```
ROSCOSMOS is a State Corporation that was established in August 2015 
to oversee and implement a comprehensive reform of the Russian space industry.
```