# What is the meaning of the ROSCOSMOS logo?

Tags: russia, roscosmos, insignia

[ROSCOSMOS](http://en.roscosmos.ru/) is the Russian [state corporation](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37243/26446) for space exploration.  Its logo is below.  **What is the official meaning or significance of the parts of the logo?**

ROSCOSMOS' main launch site ([Baikonur Cosmodrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baikonur_Cosmodrome)) is at latitude 46°N.  The [northernmost point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_northernmost_point) of Russia is 82°N.  Is it just coincidence that the edges of the red arrow seem to be inclined to these two angles?

[image: ROSCOSMOS logo]

See also: [What constellation is on the NASA logo?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/5739/26446)

Answer (score 2):

https://ria.ru/20180711/1524344892.html

> July 11, 2018 RIA News. The Roscosmos offensive corporation changed
>   its logo, abandoning the version introduced by Igor Komarov and
>   returning to the image used by the Federal Space Agency. Previously,
>   the Roscosmos logo was a red arrow, girdled with an image of an orbit.
>   This image was inscribed in a white circle. The Roskosmos website
>   still contains a description of the old "logo": "a stylized rocket
>   launch against a background of a graphic image of an orbit enclosed in
>   a circle." Now the circle is removed.

[image]